Keycloak group roles not showing in JWT
I need showing the group roles in Keycloak Token.
I created a group in Keycloak and mapped some functions.

I associated a user with the group.

I generated the token and in JWT not showing the group roles, i created a group membership mapper in roles client scope, trying a millions configurations but not worked.

